# Jmeter's HeaderManager use \r\n on Linux

Tags: jmeter, newline, multipartform-data

I'm facing with the below issue. Can somebody advise?

I have a Jmeter scenario with the file upload emulation via raw multipart POST. (not using Jmeter's default '*Use multipart/form-data for POST*'. Just build POST on my own).

Scenario works fine on WIN. However it fails when I run it on Linux.
What I got is "Invalid multipart payload format"

This is HTTPS so I can't check payload with the tcpdump (it's probably possible, just don't know how...)
Anyway I just change original URL with some non-secure, just to see the payload.
What I found there is quite strange - all headers ended with \r\n, while message use \n as a newline (which is correct as it's Linux).

Is there some thought on why does Jmeter add \r\n for all headers? Currently I can't run such request from Linux as boundary within the header and within the body seems not match each other.

Tried add headers with both HeaderManager and via API in JSR223 - doesn't help
Tried remove all ^M from JMX - doesn't help
Body is formed fine, with \n as a newline.

[image: TCP dump]

[image: Header manager in JMX]

p.s. JMX itself created on WIN, but this must not result in such behavior (tried with removed ^M. headers created/replaced within a JVM; body is built within a JVM and JVM running on Linux)

Comment: Try removing \r for Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes you think that you should see `\n` on Linux? According to the [HTTP Protocol specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2.2):

> HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF as the end-of-line marker for all protocol elements **except the entity-body** (see appendix 19.3 for tolerant applications). The end-of-line marker within an entity-body is defined by its associated media type, as described in section 3.7.
>
> ```
>   CRLF           = CR LF
> ```

So JMeter behaviour is absolutely correct and inline with what real browser does.

[image: JMeter versus real browser]

Your problem must live somewhere else, you can [decrypt your secure traffic using Wireshark](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL) and compare the requests which are being sent by JMeter and real browser, identify the differences and amend JMeter configuration to 100% match the request which browser sends.

See [Testing REST API File Uploads in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter) for an example of manually creating a multipart upload request

Comment: Thnx. This helps ))